# What data modeling tools are nosql (couchdb) developers using?

Tags: database-design, nosql, couchdb, data-modeling

At some point, I assume that anyone developing for couchdb (or other nosql option) must still identify what must be stored in each document. And it would seem that, although very rarely, every once in a while we would need to have some relationships between these documents.

So, are people still using ER-type software (like Workbench for instance) to create a visual representation of the data stored in the different documents?  Is anyone working on developing nosql specific methods to identify the data that must be capture?

Right now we are using a bullet list in wiki pages, any suggestion for something better?

Answer (score 1):

I don't anticipate tools like this to show up for a while, especially considering that CouchDB just released 1.0 a few months ago and there is still a lot that can change in the project. In addition, tools like this need to hold off until the real best practices come to light, but that can only come after years of real-world experience.

Although there are other reasons for this, relational databases simply didn't have graphical tools for years, if not decades. I can't imagine new database systems like these would progress much faster.

Comment: Thanks Dominic.  And certainly, I don't expect any GUI tools to ship soon...or at all actually.  But what I am asking is to hear from people like my team who are developing on couchdb to get some ideas to work towards best practices when it comes to data modeling.

Don't get me wrong, I've had no problem getting beyond the concepts of nosql, and I think internally we are headed in the right direction.  However, I want to hear from other couchdb developers to hear what they are using and how they are planning their documents.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a class diagram:

- replace every association with a composition or aggregation,
- see which classes must be read (as a whole) and modified,
- add simple attributes (strings or ints).

With this diagram, you have design hints:

- for "documents" granularity,
- URLs patterns,
- JSON "schemas".