# Modeling Tool for CouchDB

Tags: model, couchdb

anyone knows a good graphical helper tool, which helps me modeling my CouchDB databases?

Regs,
Rob

Comment: This isn't an exact duplicate of [What data modeling tools are nosql (couchdb) developers using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350202/what-data-modeling-tools-are-nosql-couchdb-developers-using), but it's awfully close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I certainly have not heard of any graphical modeling tools for CouchDB. In all honesty, programs like that will probably not show up for a long time. The currently ubiquitous relational databases didn't have graphical tools for a long time, possibly decades. CouchDB just released 1.0 a few months ago, and it's still a changing project in many ways.

Comment: Unluckily you seem to be right for the moment, after nearly a week of seeking some modelling tool there simply seems to be none around.